# How could I split string and keep the whitespaces, as well?

Tags: ruby, string, split, whitespace

I did the following in Python:

```
s = 'This is a text'
re.split('(\W)', s)
# => ['This', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', 'text']
```

It worked just great. How do I do the same split in Ruby?

I've tried this, but it eats up my whitespace.:

```
s = "This is a text"
s.split(/[\W]/)
# => ["This", "is", "a", "text"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `String#split` [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split):

> If pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in
>   the array as well.

This works in Ruby the same as in Python, square brackets are for specify character classes, not match groups:

```
"foo bar baz".split(/(\W)/)
# => ["foo", " ", "bar", " ", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 1):

toro2k's answer is most straightforward. Alternatively,

```
string.scan(/\w+|\W+/)
```

Comment: Tested both, they work, although I found a subtle difference if the string starts with whitespace: split will return an array starting with an empty string, then the whitespace, then the first word, etc. Whereas scan will start immediately with the first whitespace.